# redis pub sub and/or lists to implement a data collector

Tags: java, redis, queue

I'm working on a module that needs to collect data from a third party system on a schedule, say every 5 minutes.

The trigger to start data collection comes from a multi tenant UI. So, 10 tenants could tell this module to start collecting data at the same time.

I started by using a simple redis queue, all start requests from the UI are posted to the queue, the module acts as a worker, picks up the jobs and runs through them.

The problem is we need to finish one cycle of data collection in say, 1 minute, and if there are a 100 jobs, we'll take more than a minute if we go serially. And data collection needs to happen on a schedule. So the UI says run data collection every 5 minutes until I say stop!

So, we add another worker that can start taking off some load.

My question is: how do I implement the regular schedules without keeping state (scheduled thread executor) in one of the workers?

Am I thinking too hard about this and can this be done in a simpler way?

My design right now has a sort of cron job reading data collection requests from the DB every 1 minute and then putting them on a queue from where the workers pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

Using [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) would probably be a better choice than using Redis in this case.

Beanstalkd has many common points with Redis: easy to deploy, simple, light, fast, in memory by default, communication done through a simple text protocol, many [clients in various languages](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/client-libraries)... but it's dedicated to task management, it's not a database. You can add or remove workers dynamically, without any configuration to be done on beanstalkd's side.

You put jobs into a "tube" (beanstalkd name for a queue), then a worker can reserve them —one at a time. Once it reserved a job, a worker has a maximum time to complete it (called TTR —Time To Run), otherwise the job is released by beanstalkd, put again into the tube, and so may be processed by another worker.

A job is just a string; by example it could be a serialised Json describing the task to be performed.

If my understanding of your problem is correct, the UI tenants could create jobs with a normal priority to start data collection, and put them into a unique tube. One or several workers will "reserve" (take) a job from this tube, process it, delete it to inform beanstalkd it's done, then reserve another job, and so on.

`put            reserve               delete
-----> [READY] ---------> [RESERVED] --------> *poof*`

(source for this schema: beanstalkd's protocol documentation)

For a job to be processed repeatedly every 5 minutes without any scheduler, you can say every time a worker consumes a job, it creates a new one, and use the "put with delay" feature of beanstalkd when putting it into the tube. So the job will be presented to workers only when the delay is expired (5 minutes in your case).

When the UI wants to cancel the remaining jobs, it can just pick and delete allof them from the tube. Or if you want the workers to delete them, the UI can put into the tube a cancelling job (see it as a message) with a higher priority than data collection jobs. You could also use another tube, assuming you listen to it in another thread than the one dedicated to data collection.

My knowledge and understanding of your problem is obviously limited, but you certainly can refine these ideas to solve your exact problem.

Comment: Beenstalkd is a job queue that I could use, but it was last updated in 2014 as far as I can see. I'll go take a look at something more recent. Only reason for sticking to redis was that we already use it and I didn't want to add another component.

Comment: It doesn't evolve because it doesn't need it. It's stable, simple, and intends to remain like that. I'm a big fan of Redis, and Beanstalk is a product I compare to Redis. But I understand your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Your task could be done with [Redisson](https://redisson.org). It offers [SchedulerService](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/9.-distributed-services#94-distributed-scheduled-executor-service) backed by Redis. It also supports cron-expressions. Usage example:

```
public class RunnableTask implements Runnable {

    @RInject
    private RedissonClient redissonClient;

    private Object param;

    public RunnableTask() {
    }

    public RunnableTask(Object param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ... 
    }

}

RScheduledExecutorService executorService = redisson.getExecutorService("myExecutor");
schedule(new RunnableTask(), CronSchedule.of("10 0/5 * * * ?"));
```

You can run worker right in your application or run it in a standalone [Redisson Node](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/12.-Standalone-node).